# How to pass pointer to multidimensional array of abstract data type

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have read some material on passing pointers to multidimensional arrays, but I am not able to get it to work for myself.

I have:

```
/* This code basically, in order, does this--or tries to:
    - Create 2D array of cell structs
    - Create info_pass detailing certain attributes of the 2D array
         + in particular, I am trying to include a pointer to the 2D array so that I
           can pass the info_pass struct between functions and update the contents of 
           the 2D array in each function.
    - The updating is done in struct info_pass* update(...){}
    - ... however, in my full program, there are several other functions it is passed 
      to, so being able to pass a pointer that allows manipulation of the 2D array is
      what I'm really after.
*/

struct info_pass {
    /* stuff */
    struct cell* master;
};
struct cell {
    /* values */
    /* lots of pointers to other cells */
};
struct info_pass* genesis() {                 /* creating an the multiD array */
    /* stuff */
    struct cell* (*cells)[width];
    cells = malloc(sizeof(struct cell) * width * length);

    struct info_pass* keycard = NULL;
    keycard = malloc(sizeof(struct info_pass));
    /* assign values to key card */
    keycard->master = cells;     /* problem here?! */  <==== (A)

    /* update cells */

    return keycard;                           /* therefore problem here too */
}
struct info_pass* update(struct info_pass* key) {
    struct info_pass* keyRef = NULL;
    keyRef = malloc(sizeof(struct info_pass));
    keyRef = key;                             /* and of course here */

    struct cell* home1 = NULL;
    home1 = malloc(sizeof(struct cell));

    /*here I want to update the multidimensional array*/ <===== (B)
    /*... and then send it back ...*/
    return keyRef;
 }
```

Error @ **(A)** = warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type.

Error @ **(B)** = error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer.

Just hoping for a shove in the right direction.

**EDIT**

As per ThePosey's suggestion, I will show more of the code involved in the 'Error: subscripted value is neither pointer nor array`s. I will add it below rather than putting it into the above code sample so as to preserve the original question's state for future context.

```
struct info_pass* update(struct info_pass* key) {      

    /* passing data, including a pointer to a 2D array from info_pass     */
    /* struct then I want to access the 2D array and change it's contents */
    /* contents and then send it back in another info_pass struct         */

    struct info_pass* keyRef = NULL;      
    keyRef = malloc(sizeof(struct info_pass));
    keyRef = key;                     /* to pass the info back afterwards */

    int len = keyRef->length;
    int wid = keyRef->width;

    struct cell* home1 = NULL;
    home1 = malloc(sizeof(struct cell));
    home1 = key->masterRef[len][wid];       /* to access and change the data */

    int fate = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for (a = 0; a < len; a++) {
            for (b = 0; b <  wid; b++) {
                    if (keyRef->masterRef[a][b].go_up.state == 1) { 
     /* just trying different styles of calls */
                            fate++;
                    } if (home1[a][b].go_down.state == 1) {
                            fate++;
                    } if (home1[a][b]->go_left->state == 1) {
                            fate++;
                    } if (home1[a][b]->go_right->state == 1) {
                            fate++;
     /* there more calls to the array, and all generate the same error: */
     /* subscripted value is neither array nor pointer */
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error at @A is from trying to assign a `cell***` to a `cell*`. If you want to create a multi dimensional (from the code it looks like you want a 2D length x width) array you would do the following:

```
struct cell* cells[length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    //give each row width number of cell structs
    cells[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct cell) * width);
}
```

Attempting to help with the rest of your question. You would change

```
struct info_pass {
    /* stuff */
    struct cell* master;
};
```

to

```
struct info_pass {
    /* stuff */
    struct cell** master;
};
```

but you'd probably also need to keep the length and width info in that struct as well so you know the size of the array. After that wherever you have an info pass you can access the individual cell elements by doing something like:

```
struct cell* single_cell = &my_info_pass->master[lengthIndex][widthIndex];
```

or get the values directly if you had like a cell_id int in the cell struct for example:

```
int cell_value = my_info_pass->master[lengthIndex][widthIndex].cell_id;
```

Without a more specific case and exact code it's hard to narrow in on the part you're not understanding. Hopefully this helps a bit.

Comment: It is a 2D array, indeed! Will your method of creation make it any easier to pass a pointer to it? I do not see how it would remedy that difficulty. I will edit the OP with a brief explanation.

Comment: "passing" is a verb associated with function arguments. What might you mean by "passing" a pointer to a piece of data like an array?

Comment: @RonBurk The pointer points to the piece of data so that the data can be manipulated--it is *not* a parameter. Similar to a linked list.

Comment: Just able to work with your edit now. If I want to loop the entire 2D array after passing it into a different function, and I use `struct cell* current = &my_info_pass->master[lengthIndex][widthIndex]`, I could access the status of a value within that cell by adding `->status` to the end of the above command, right? Well, this is still generating an error! In fact, that is the exact syntax I have been using! The compiler still doesn't like the `assignment from incompatible pointer type`s. Also, my program is around 200 lines long so I don't think posting it here will get me any favors...! :/

Comment: I also tried to shorten the assignment by: `struct cell* current = &my_info_pass->masterRef;`, thinking I could then use: `current[length][width]->status` for my loop. This also did not please the compiler.

Comment: Update: Very helpful so far! You were spot on about changing the structure of how I created the 2D array. Not entirely sure why my method didn't work... I'll have to think it over later. Now I am just left with a batch of **(B)** errors.

Comment: maybe post some of the code in an edit that is giving you the B errors with any additional context needed

Comment: @ThePosey Thanks for all your help so far! I updated the question with more code and some explanatory comments.

Comment: I'm not sure that continuing like this is going to help you much. I would recommend going through a tutorial on C pointers and double pointers. It seems like you are missing the concept of what they actually are and what the indexing is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but a note that needs some formatting. :-) It's handy to understand that "arrays" in C are just pointer arithmetic. For example:

```
char* ptr = "abcd";

    printf("Letter = %c\n", ptr[1]);
    printf("Letter = %c\n", 1[ptr]); // Same damn thing!
    printf("Letter = %c\n", *(1 + ptr)); // and again!
```

So, when you're doing what looks like "array indexing" to you, C is just adding things and indirecting through them. The syntax "x[y]" means "add x to y and use the result as a pointer". (the caveat, of course, is that C multiplies integers by the size of the thing pointed to before adding them to a pointer)

IOW, the [] operator really means "add and indirect".

Does good old ANSI C have multidimensional arrays? Not really, not in the sense that a language like FORTRAN that uses them a lot does. But, as long as you've got simple arrays and pointer arithmetic, you can roll your own. So, if I want a one-dimensional array, all I need is a pointer to some memory that malloc() supplied. But if I want a two-dimensional array, then I need an array of pointers, each of which points to some memory that malloc() returned. Because this:

```
int** Matrix = MallocMatrix(3, 5);

Matrix[2][3] = 0;
```

means "add 2*sizeof(int*) to Matrix and indirect. then add 3*sizeof(int) to that and indirect."